# Limit h to 0 question... Is this right?

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}{h}
$$

I can cancel the top out by multiplying by 
$$
\frac{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}
$$
and get
$$
=\frac{a+h-a}{h(\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a})}
$$
which just equals
$$
\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a})}
$$
Then you cancel $h$ out and get
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}\xrightarrow{h \to0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}
$$

Is this fine?

Comment: $(a-b)(a-b)=a^2-2ab+b^2$, not $a^2-b^2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have a typo, but multiply $$\frac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt a}{h}$$
by
$$\frac{\sqrt{a+h}\color{red}{+}\sqrt a}{\sqrt{a+h}\color{red}{+}\sqrt a}\ (=1).$$

Also, note that
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt a)(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt a)}&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(a+h)-a}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt a)}\\&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt a}\\&=\frac{1}{\color{red}{2}\sqrt a}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that it doesn't work with 
$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}$
it is a problem with that this expression is undefined for $h=0$. As it is pointed out
$\displaystyle\frac{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}$ is the correct approach and note that this expression equals to 1 even when $h=0$.

Comment: It was a typo and then a carried on mistake

Comment: @user156684: Your typo became a didactic opportunity, then.